# Why write the solution of the harmonic oscillator form 1 is equal to writing form 2?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Why write the solution of the harmonic oscillator form $$\psi=A\cos\omega_0 t+B\sin \omega_0t$$ is equal to writing form $$\psi=C_1e^{i\omega_0t}+C_2e^{-i\omega_0t}$$?

I would like to see how one implies the other or vice versa, the harmonic oscillator equation is:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\psi+\omega_0^2\psi=0;\;\;\omega_0\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: this can help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/simple-harmonic-oscillator-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Euler's formula on the second expression, we see

\begin{align*}
\psi&=C_1e^{i\omega_0t}+C_2e^{-i\omega_0t} \\
&= C_1(\cos{\omega_0t}+i\sin{\omega_0t})+C_2(\cos(-\omega_0t)+i\sin(-\omega_0t)) \\
&= C_1(\cos{\omega_0t}+i\sin{\omega_0t})+C_2(\cos{\omega_0t}-i\sin{\omega_0t}) \\
&= (C_1+C_2)\cos{\omega_0t}+i(C_1-C_2)\sin{\omega_0t}\:.
\end{align*}

If we then let $C_1=\frac{1}{2}(A-Bi),C_2=\frac{1}{2}(A+Bi)$, you get the first formula.

Answer (score 1):

$$\psi=A\cos\omega_0 t+B\sin \omega_0t$$

From
$$\psi=C_1e^{i\omega_0t}+C_2e^{-i\omega_0t}$$
we can use Euler's equation:
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+ i\sin x$$
to get:
$$\psi=C_1*(\cos \omega_0t+ i\sin \omega_0t)+C_2*(\cos \omega_0t- i\sin \omega_0t)$$
$$\psi=(C_1+C_2) \cos \omega_0t+ (iC_1-iC_2)\sin \omega_0t$$
Finally define $$A= C_1+C_2  , B=iC_1-iC_2$$
Hence
$$\psi=A\cos\omega_0 t+B\sin \omega_0t$$