# How to solve harmonic oscillator differential equation: $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \dfrac{kx}{m} = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I am able to solve simple differential equations like :

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2 + 2x$$

We simply bring $dx$ to other site and integrate.

But how do we find solutions of differential equations like :

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \dfrac{kx}{m} = 0$$

?

We have been told the solution is $x(t) = A\cos ( \omega t + \phi_o)$ where $\omega\ =\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}$

but how do we actually find it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For convenience, $$x''+\omega^2x=0.$$

**Solution 1**:

Multiply by $2x'$, to get

$$2x'x''+2\omega^2xx'=0=(x'^2+\omega^2x^2)'.$$

After integration we get a separable equation

$$x'^2+\omega^2x^2=C^2,$$ or
$$\frac{x'}{\sqrt{A^2-x^2}}=\omega.$$

Integrating,

$$\arcsin\left(\frac x{A}\right)=\omega t+\phi.$$

---

**Solution 2**:

Let $D$ denote the differentiation operator. We can rewrite the equation as

$$(D^2+\omega^2)x=0$$ and factor

$$(D-i\omega)(D+i\omega)x=0.$$

Indeed, $(D-i\omega)(D+i\omega)x=(D-i\omega)(x'+i\omega x)=x''+i\omega x'-i\omega(x'+i\omega x)=x''+\omega^2x$.

If we define $y=(D+i\omega)x$, we need to solve

$$(D-i\omega)y=0,$$ i.e.

$$\frac{y'}y=i\omega.$$

The solution is easily found to be

$$y=Ce^{i\omega t}.$$

Now we need to solve

$$(D+i\omega)x=y=Ce^{i\omega t}.$$

The solution is found by combining the general solution of the homogenous equation, $C'e^{-i\omega t}$, found similarly, and a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation.

When trying $y=C''e^{i\omega t}$, we have

$$C''i\omega e^{i\omega t}+C''i\omega e^{i\omega t}=Ce^{i\omega t}$$ which is a valid solution.

Then

$$x=C'e^{-i\omega t}+C''e^{i\omega t}.$$

As the solution must be real, it can be rewritten as

$$x=C'\cos(\omega t)+C''\sin(\omega t)=A\sin(\omega t +\phi).$$

---

**Solution 3**:

We recall that $(\sin(t))''=-\sin(t)$ and $(\cos(t))''=-\cos(t)$.

Then scaling with the coefficient $\omega$, $(\sin(\omega t))''=-\omega^2\sin(\omega t)$ and $(\cos(\omega t))''=-\omega^2\cos(\omega t)$.

These are two independent solutions of the differential equation, and as the equation is of the second order, the linear combination of these two functions is the general solution

$$x=C\cos(\omega t)+S\sin(\omega t).$$

---

**Solution 4:**

The characteristic equation is $\lambda^2+\omega^2=0$ and has the solutions $\lambda=\pm i\omega$. Hence the general solution

$$C_+e^{i\omega t}+C_-e^{-i\omega t}.$$

As we want a real solution, after expansion and cancelling of the imaginary part,

$$x=C\cos\omega t+S\sin\omega t.$$

---

**Solution 5:**

The equation is *autonomous* (no explicit appearance of time).

Let $v:=x'$. We have $x''=\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{dv}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=v\dfrac{dv}{dx}$. The equation turns to

$$v\frac{dv}{dx}+\omega^2 x=0$$ or $$v^2+\omega^2 x^2=C$$ and we join the solution 1.

---

**Solution 6:**

Let us try the entire series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n$.

We get

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n(n-1)a_nt^{n-2}+\omega^2a_nt^n)=0,$$

giving the recurrence

$$a_{n+2}=-\frac{\omega^2a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$ and $a_0,a_1$ are free.

Hence,

$$x=a_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-\omega^2)^n\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}+a_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-\omega^2)^n\frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

We recognize $a_0\cos(\omega t)+\dfrac{a_1}\omega\sin(\omega t)$.

---

**Solution 7:**

Let us try and find the Taylor development of $x$ around $t=0$. We have no information on $x_0:=x(0)$ nor $x'_0=x'(0)$, which are free parameters. Then

$$x''(0)=-\omega^2x(0)=-\omega^2x_0,\\
x'''(0)=-\omega^2x'(0)=-\omega^2x'_0,\\
x''''(0)=-\omega^2x''(0)=\omega^4x_0,\\
x'''''(0)=-\omega^2x'''(0)=\omega^4x'_0,\\
\cdots$$

Hence by induction,

$$x^{(2n)}(0)=(-\omega^2)^nx_0,\\x^{(2n+1)}(0)=(-\omega^2)^nx'_0.$$

Finally, in a way similar to solution 6, $x(t)=x_0\cos(\omega t)+\dfrac{x'_0}\omega\sin(\omega t)$.

---

**Solution 8:**

Let us rewrite the second order ODE as a system of the first order,

$$\begin{cases}x'=y,\\y'=-\omega^2x,\end{cases}.$$

In matrix form

$$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-\omega^2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}.$$

We know that the solution of such a system is obtained from the exponential of the matrix, itself a function of its Eigenvalues. The Eigenvalues are $\pm i\omega$ and the solution will be of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\omega}&0\\0&e^{-i\omega}\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}.$$

For a real solution, we must have $b=a^*$.

Alternatively, we can compute the powers of the matrix, let $M$. We observe that

$$M^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-\omega^2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-\omega^2&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\omega^2&0\\0&-\omega^2\end{bmatrix}=-\omega^2I.$$

Hence the powers are alternatively $(-\omega^2)^{2n}I$ and $(-\omega^2)^{2n}M$, and we obtain the exponential as

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty M^n\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{pmatrix}\frac{t^k}{k!}=\left(I\cos(\omega t)+M\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{pmatrix}.$$

---

**Solution 9:**

By Laplace,

$$\mathcal L(x''+\omega x)=s^2\mathcal Lx-sx_0-x'_0+\omega^2\mathcal Lx=0$$

and

$$\mathcal Lx=\frac{sx_0+x'_0}{s^2+\omega^2}.$$

Reverting to the original by means of a table,

$$x(t)=x_0\cos(\omega t)+\frac{x'_0}{\omega}\sin(\omega t).$$

The resolution by the Fourier transform is uneasy as it requires the use of distributions.

---

**Solution 10:**

We can integrate the equation numerically, for instance with a Runge-Kutta solver. But we have a dependency on three parameters, namely $\omega$ and the initial conditions $x(0),x'(0)$.

We can remove the first dependency by rescaling time, let $\tau:=\omega t$, giving

$$\ddot x+x=0.$$

Accordingly, we update the initial condition $\dot x(0)=\dfrac{x'(0)}{\omega}$. To remove the dependency on the initial conditions, we observe that the equation is (luckily) linear and it suffices to solve for the two canonical cases $x(0)=1,\dot x(0)=0$ and $x(0)=0,\dot x(0)=1$.

Here is a plot of the results of integration:

[image]

Now the general solution is a linear combination of these two canonical functions, that can be tabulated once for all.

---

**Solution 11:**

By Picard's method, we start with a linear solution that satisfies the initial conditions

$$z_0(t)=x'_0t+x_0.$$

Then we integrate $x''=-\omega^2x$ twice and still fulfilling the initial conditions, get

$$z_1(t)=x'_0t+x_0-\omega^2\int_0^t\int_0^t(x'_0t+x_0)dt=x'_0t+x_0-\omega^2\frac{t^3}{3!}x'_0-\omega^2\frac{t^2}2.$$

The next step yields

$$z_2(t)=x'_0t+x_0-\omega^2\frac{t^3}{3!}x'_0-\omega^2\frac{t^2}2+\omega^4\frac{t^5}{5!}x'_0-\omega^4\frac{t^4}{4!}$$

and one recognizes the pattern for the sine and cosine developments.

Comment: Regarding solution 4 it's worth pointing out that $C_+$ and $C_-$ are complex and that $\bar{C_+} = C_-$ if $x(t)$ is real, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/simple-harmonic-oscillator-solution)

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$x''(t)+\frac{kx(t)}{m}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^2x(t)}{\text{d}t^2}+\frac{kx(t)}{m}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assume a solution will be proportional to $e^{\lambda t}$ for some constant $\lambda$.

Substitute $x(t)=e^{\lambda t}$ into the differential equation:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left(e^{\lambda t}\right)+\frac{ke^{\lambda t}}{m}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left(e^{\lambda t}\right)=\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}$:

---

$$\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}+\frac{ke^{\lambda t}}{m}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{\lambda t}\left(\lambda^2+\frac{k}{m}\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Since $e^{\lambda t}\ne 0$ for any finite $\lambda$, the zeros must come from the polynomial:

---

$$\lambda^2+\frac{k}{m}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{k+m\lambda^2}{m}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\lambda=\pm\frac{i\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{m}}$$

Comment: Assuming that it has the exponential form feels a bit like cheating.

Comment: We can use Laplace Transform but I don't know if the OP is familiar with that

Comment: how did you guess that it will be proportional to $e^{\lambda t}$ ?

Comment: I didn't guess that, It is!

Comment: For a systematic approach to this kind of problem (= linear differential equations with constant coefficients) there are special tools. For instance, there is the notion of "Fourier transform": writing an unknown member of a fairly general class of functions as some kind of infinite linear combination of sines and cosines. For this particular equation it turns out that the solutions are linear combinations of only one cosine and one sine wave, both with the exact frequency $\sqrt{k/m}/2\pi.$

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you are solving $\ddot{x}=-\omega_0^2x$. Double dot over $x$ means double derivative wrt time $t$. This is easily seen to be equivalent to $$\Big(\frac{d}{dt}+i\omega_0\Big)\Big(\frac{d}{dt}-i\omega_0\Big)x=0.$$ This would imply $$\Big(\frac{d}{dt}-i\omega_0\Big)x= const$$ You can take it from here using the method you use by transferring $dt$ on the other side and integrating.

Comment: Thank you this solution seems easiest for me, but how can we take $\frac{d}{dt}$ outside? is it a term?

Comment: you can put $\Big(\frac{d}{dt}-i\omega_0\Big)x= 0$. Then the equation is satisfied. Then it follows that  $\frac{d}{dt}=i\omega_0x $.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? $$\int 1/x(t) dx=\int (\mathrm{const}/x(t)+i\omega_0) dt$$. The RHS contains the solution Im looking for

Answer (score 1):

The equation:

$y'' = -k^2 \cdot y$

Has the completesolution:

$y = f(x) = c_1 \cos(kx) + c_2 \sin(kx)$

Proof:

First we define two function g(x) and h(x)

$g(x)=f(x)\cos(kx)-\frac{1}{k}f'(x)\sin(kx)$

$h(x) = f(x)\sin(kx)+\frac{1}{k}f'(x)\cos(kx)$

We differentiate g(x) and h(x): (Using the product and chain rule)

$g'(x)=f'(x)\cos(kx)-f(x)k\sin(kx)-\frac{1}{k}(f''(x)\sin(kx)+f'(x)k\cos(kx))$

$h'(x)=f'(x)\sin(kx)+f(x)k\cos(kx)+\frac{1}{k}(f''(x)\cos(kx)-f'(x)k\sin(kx))$

Now comes the critical point. Lets assume the function f(x) is a solution to the differentialequation. If and only if f(x) is a solution the we can write:

$f''(x)=-k^2f(x)$

We can use this in the g(x) and h(x) functions and substitute for f''(x) and reduce the expression:

$g'(x)=f'(x)\cos(kx)-f(x)k\sin(kx)-\frac{1}{k}(\color{red}{-k^2f(x)}\sin(kx)+f'(x)k\cos(kx)) \Leftrightarrow$

$g'(x)=0$

$h'(x)=f'(x)\sin(kx)+f(x)k\cos(kx)+\frac{1}{k}(\color{red}{-k^2f(x)}\cos(kx)-f'(x)k\sin(kx)) \Leftrightarrow$

$h'(x)=0$

When the derivative of the functions are 0, then the functions themself must be constants:

$g(x)=c_1 \;\;\;$   and   $\;\;\;h(x)=c_2$

So we insert this in the two first equations:

$c_1=f(x)\cos(kx)-\frac{1}{k}f'(x)\sin(kx)$

$c_2 = f(x)\sin(kx)+\frac{1}{k}f'(x)\cos(kx)$

We multiply the $c_1$ equation with cos(kx) and we multiply the $c_2$ equation with sin(kx):

$c_1 \cos(kx)=f(x)\cos(kx)^2-\frac{1}{k}f'(x)\sin(kx)\cos(kx)$

$c_2 \sin(kx) = f(x)\sin(kx)^2+\frac{1}{k}f'(x)\cos(kx)\sin(kx)$

We then add the two equations:

$c_1 \cos(kx) + c_2 \sin(kx) = f(x)\cos(kx)^2-\frac{1}{k}f'(x)\sin(kx)\cos(kx) + f(x)\sin(kx)^2+\frac{1}{k}f'(x)\cos(kx)\sin(kx) \Leftrightarrow$

$c_1 \cos(kx) + c_2 \sin(kx) = f(x)\cos(kx)^2 + f(x)\sin(kx)^2 \Leftrightarrow$

$c_1 \cos(kx) + c_2 \sin(kx) = f(x)(\cos(kx)^2 + \sin(kx)^2) \Leftrightarrow$

$c_1 \cos(kx) + c_2 \sin(kx) = f(x)(1) \Leftrightarrow$

$c_1 \cos(kx) + c_2 \sin(kx) = f(x)$

All that is left is to test if this is a solutions by inserting in the differential equation. If you do that, you will find it is a solution.

Q.E.D