# Similar as simple harmonic oscillator differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In some physics problem I got next differential equation: x''=kx
I know that simple harmonic oscillator problem are solved using complex numbers, but i don't know why solution is like: $x=A\cos\left(bt+d\right)$

I tried to solve this way.

$x''-kx=0$

$x=ae^{rt}$

$ar^2e^{rt}-kae^{rt}=0$

$r^2-k=0$

$$x=ae^{\pm\sqrt{k}t}$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [This might be the solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1575291/1181491)

Comment: Note that $\mathrm e^x =\cos(-\mathrm i x)+\mathrm i \sin(-\mathrm i x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation should be $x^{"}+kx=0$ where $k \ge 0$, in your case k should be negative and $r$ will have imaginary solutions so it brings sin and cos.